# Replace contents within a div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a small grocery shopping app.

I want to make a page where the user see his/her shopping cart contents on clicking a button.

I created the template where the contents should show up in the white space.
My idea is to store every item the user chooses in an array. For example:

```
var items = ["1 Chicken", "2 Tomatoes", "3 Spinach"]
```

Using this array I want to add these items line by line in the white space and then present the total amount to be paid. Kind of like a receipt. 
I'm not sure how to do this using JQuery.

Also, the contents of the  should be empty when there's no items in the cart.

I did some research and I think I'm supposed to .html()? Though, I'm not sure about the logic behind what I want to achieve.

Here's the [fiddle of the template](https://jsfiddle.net/a87v5qkr/3/). (The cdn links aren't working for some reason)

Could someone please help me with the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
function getOrder()
{
   arr  = ["1 chicken","2 orange","3 milk"]
   for(i = 0;i<3;i++)
   {
     $("#elementId").append('<p>'+arr[i]+'</p><br>')
   }
}

//blank <div> tag in your page body somewhere     
<div id="elementId">

</div>
<button onclick="getOrder()">Get Order Details</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible not to have it in a listview? I just want it to show up as plain text line by line in the white space

Comment: Yes, instead of ul, just have a div and keep appending <p>text...</p><br>

Comment: How would I remove the existing <p> with new ones when I make a new order? P.S the ul is not working. I'm using JQuery Mobile btw

Comment: Could you please show me how I can do it with the <p> element?

Comment: oh, JQuery mobile ?, Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200767/discussion-between-vs12-and-shane-dsilva).